# differentiable equal r-forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be two $r$-forms continuous in $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open.

If $\int_M \alpha =\int_M \beta  $ for all surface $M\subseteq U$
  dimension $r$, compact, with boundary, then show that $\alpha=\beta$.

But if $\alpha-\beta\neq 0$  then $\int_M\alpha-\beta \neq 0$ always? No matter who it is $M$?
I.e., is the condition "for all" $M$ necessary?

Comment: Are you asking whether the statement is true or false? Or do you know it is true and want to know how to prove it? Or do you know it is false and you are looking for a counterexample? Please add some context to your question, including your thoughts on the problem (whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thrilled :)

Comment: No, it states that if $\alpha-\beta\ne 0$ then *there is* a compact $r$ dimensional subset $M$ of $U$ such that $\int_M(\alpha-\beta)\ne0$.

Comment: Where is this from? How do you integrate a form on a manifold with boundary?